# django-plotly-dash, 'Error at Line 0 expected string or bytes-like object' in base.html?

Tags: django

I am working through a tutorial on connecting django-plotly-dash to a Django project.  Before I added the Plotly components, I was able to access my templates without issue.  Once I set up the various Plotly requirements, I now get this error when I try to go to the main page:

[error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtPMe.jpg)

I'm not sure where to start figuring out what this is telling me, there are some similar issues on Google (and Stack Overflow) bet I am not seeing finding anything that seems related.  Also, I'm basically a noob, so be gentle.